# determine the address of the allocated region in VirtualAlloc?

Tags: windows, memory-management, memory-address, ollydbg, virtualalloc

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) VirtualAlloc allows the value of address parameter to be null and the  "the system determines where to allocate the region."

The question is, is there a way to know the allocated address? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same reference document about `VirtualAlloc` states concerning the value returned by the function:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the base address of the allocated region of pages.